# Why do I get the following error attempting to install memcached in my django app?

Tags: python, django, memcached

I'm trying to add memcached to a django app . So I installed it using the command

```
sudo apt get install memcached
```

When I Attempt to check the install using

```
memcached -vv
```

I get the error

```
can't run as root without the -u switch
```

I'm not sure what this error means. I need to understand before I attempt to research solutions.

Comment: This forum thread might help: https://forumweb.hosting/13657-cant-run-as-root-without-the-u-switch.html

Comment: Not sure what to get from the thread, which does seem to address the same issue and maybe its because Im running the command as root. But is there a better way to install memcached and check if it's installed than the way I've tried to do it?

Comment: I found this tutorial to help find a solution : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-memcached-on-ubuntu-16-04